# Would Western Digitals reduced power spinup jumper feature lower rpm speed and temps?

Tags: hard-drive

Would Western Digital's reduced power spinup jumper feature lower rpm speed and temps? I have a mini PC and am seeing a little high for my liking temps on my WD Scorpio Black 7200rpm drive, and am wondering is this a feature I should use. (not worried about the side effects)

And what exactly does it do/not do.

More info: http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/other/2579-001116.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the link you posted is broken. Here's the correct one:
http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/other/2579-001116.pdf

The document does not mention reduced RPMs and this is understandable, given the fact that this *reduced power spinup* just limits the current the drive is using when spinning up.

Comment: How can it lower the voltage of the spin-up, if the RPM of the motor isn't reduced as well? In that case, why wouldn't the drive operate at the lower voltage all the time?

Comment: @DemonCamber - There's no mention of *"lower voltage"* at all in relation to this RPS feature.  You seem to interchange "current" with "voltage", which of course is wrong.

Comment: Yes I was, thanks had no idea they were different.